Stop annoying 'Shortcut X missed N times' pop-ups in IntelliJ IDEA
I keep getting 'helpful' pop-ups scolding me for not using keyboard shortcuts I don't want or need. I've been manually disabling them as they come up but I'd like to disable them all entirely, for any and all shortcuts. The last straw was being told that instead of using the back/forward buttons on my mouse, I should be pressing two to three keyboard keys instead.
I have tried disabling "Key Promoter X" Notifications in Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Notifications but that did nothing as far as I can tell.
I don't want to disable all pop-ups, just this specific kind of pop-up.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 (Ultimate Edition).


The keyboard shortcut notifications you see are provided by the Key Promoter X plugin, that you have installed. Perhaps you should disable this plugin in the plugin settings?

Thank you! It was automatically installed via an automatically-generated ./.idea/externalDependencies.xml file so I had no idea where it was coming from.
